# Excel Listobject resize and offset range cell

Tags: excel, resize, range, offset, listobject

I have a Listobject in a particular sheet:

```
Dim ftstbl As ListObject
        Set ftstbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("employees").ListObjects(1)
```

I want to refer a range aoutside of the listobject with repect to one of the headers of the listobject
But the follwoing does not work:

```
Dim highlights As Range
        Set highlights = ftstbl.ListColumns("name").Range.Item(1).Resize(2,).Offset(-4, 0)
```

basically I would like to name a range "highlights" which is 4 cells on top of the header "name" and is two cells "high".

I read a couple of answers in stackOverflow and played around with using or not uing a 0 as argument for resize and offset at no avail.

Some ideas?

note: the code is running inside of:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

thanks

Edit 1:
The error is:
[image]

EROOR 2:
When including the 0 in Resize
[image]

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: I added the errors to the question.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print ftstbl.ListColumns("name").Range.Item(1).Resize(2).Address` return?

Comment: it gives: $E$5:$E$6

Comment: Omg I think Resize(2,) does not work, neither resize(2,0) only resize(2)